# how to change the source of an image, which is in the innerhtml of another element?

Tags: javascript, html, image, innerhtml

i have a button with an image in its innerhtml and i want to change this image

```
<button id="button1"><img src="someimage.png"></button>
```

i tried something like this (in a function, which is called by the button):

```
this.innerhtml.setAttribute("src","someotherimage.png");
this.innerhtml="<img src="someotherimage.png">";
```

i have multiple buttons which trigger the same function, but i want the function to only change the img of the button, which triggered the function.
Can i do this without giving the image an ID and using a buttload of if-statements to match the image-id to the button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.innerHTML` simply returns a string. And strings don't have the methods a DOM element has. You could select the image as a child element of the button and assign a new value to its `src` property with the expression `document.querySelector("button img").src="newURL.png"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `event` parameter, take the `currentTarget` (the element the listener is attached to - which will be the button) and from there you can get the child `<img>` with `.children[0]`.

```
.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.children[0].src = 'someotherimage.png';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

More specific to img tag

```
.addEventListener('click', ($event) => {
    event.target.querySelector('img').src="someotherimage.png";
 });
```